# Facebook no_feed_story not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-feed, facebook-stream-story

I am trying to post to Facebook but no feed story flag doesnt seem to be working.
The code that i am trying is

```
FB.api('/me/marsmsps:review?recipe=https://sultry-brook-4860.herokuapp.com/',
    'post', 
'no_feed_story=1',
function(response) {
       if (!response || response.error) {
          alert('Error occured'+response.error.message);
       } else {
          alert('successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
       }
    });
```

Whether i set the no_feed_story flag or not, in all cases, the feed is visible on my profile with my id but is not visible from my friend's id.
Am I doing some thing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

try 
no_feed_story=true.
you used no_feed_story=1, but Facebook expects it to be true or false.

Comment: According to the Facebook docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/), this isn't correct. The example they give is `no_feed_story=1`.

Comment: I think either should work. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/14/new-page-apis/ gives the examples `no_feed_story=false` and `is_hidden=true`.